# How to send all HTTP request errors to the Sentry in a Reactjs app in 2023?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sentry, sentryreact

I've developed a `react@16.14.0` app, and I want to log every HTTP request error in Sentry. I read the Sentry documentation and used the `captureException` function of Sentry in the all `catch` block of my HTTP requests.

```
     .
     .
     .
try {
        await Api.retryConfirmationEmail(response); // This is a HTTP request
    } catch (err) {
        Sentry.captureException(err);
    }
    .
    .
    .
```

And this is the Sentry configuration:

```
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/react";
import { Integrations } from "@sentry/tracing";

const init = () => {
    Sentry.init({
        dsn: *******,
        integrations: [new Integrations.BrowserTracing()],
        tracesSampleRate: 1.0,
    });
};
```

And I invoked the `init` function in the root JSX file:

```
.
.
.
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    logger.init();
};
.
.
.
```

And it works, but it doesn't cover all HTTP request errors.

Why is the HTTP request error doesn't log in to Sentry?

Comment: Have you ever invoked `init()` somewhere in your script? It seems like you have the Sentry init within this function.

Comment: @node_modules
Yes, I have invoked it in the main JSX file.

Answer (score 0):

try call `init` on `Sentry` direct

like this

```
Sentry.init({
  dsn: *******,
  integrations: [new Integrations.BrowserTracing()],
  tracesSampleRate: 1.0,
});
```

or make sure you call your `init()` function